# SHAP Explainer ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')

Tags: pytorch, shap

It works fine when I run it on Linux, but the error occurred when I ran it on Windows 10. Please contribute to its successful operation in Windows 10.

Code:

```
import shap
# print the JS visualization code to the notebook
shap.initjs()

def prob(data):
    return model.forward(Variable(torch.from_numpy(data)).float()).detach().numpy().reshape(-1, 1)

shap_explainer = shap.KernelExplainer(prob, 
                                      X_train.numpy(), 
                                      link="logit")
shap_values = shap_explainer.shap_values(X_test.numpy(), nsamples=100)
```

Error:

> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> 2                                       X_train.numpy(),
> 3                                       link="logit")
> ----> 4 shap_values = shap_explainer.shap_values(X_test.numpy(), nsamples=100)
>
> D:\Software\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\shap\explainers_kernel.py in
> shap_values(self, X, **kwargs)
> 188                 if self.keep_index:
> 189                     data = convert_to_instance_with_index(data, column_name, index_value[i:i +
> 1], index_name)
> --> 190                 explanations.append(self.explain(data, **kwargs))
> 191                 if kwargs.get("gc_collect", False):
> 192                     gc.collect()
>
> D:\Software\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\shap\explainers_kernel.py in
> explain(self, incoming_instance, **kwargs)
> 386             phi_var = np.zeros((self.data.groups_size, self.D))
> 387             for d in range(self.D):
> --> 388                 vphi, vphi_var = self.solve(self.nsamples / self.max_samples, d)
> 389                 phi[self.varyingInds, d] = vphi
> 390                 phi_var[self.varyingInds, d] = vphi_var
>
> D:\Software\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\shap\explainers_kernel.py in
> solve(self, fraction_evaluated, dim)
> 563             elif self.l1_reg == "auto" or self.l1_reg == "bic" or self.l1_reg == "aic":
> 564                 c = "aic" if self.l1_reg == "auto" else self.l1_reg
> --> 565                 nonzero_inds = np.nonzero(LassoLarsIC(criterion=c).fit(mask_aug, eyAdj_aug).coef_)[0]
> 566
> 567             # use a fixed regularization coeffcient
>
> D:\Software\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model_least_angle.py
> in fit(self, X, y, copy_X)    1862         if copy_X is None:    1863
> copy_X = self.copy_X
> -> 1864         X, y = self._validate_data(X, y, y_numeric=True)    1865     1866         X, y, Xmean, ymean, Xstd =
> LinearModel._preprocess_data(
>
> D:\Software\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in
> _validate_data(self, X, y, reset, validate_separately, **check_params)
> 431                 y = check_array(y, **check_y_params)
> 432             else:
> --> 433                 X, y = check_X_y(X, y, **check_params)
> 434             out = X, y
> 435
>
> D:\Software\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in
> inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
> 61             extra_args = len(args) - len(all_args)
> 62             if extra_args <= 0:
> ---> 63                 return f(*args, **kwargs)
> 64
> 65             # extra_args > 0
>
> D:\Software\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in
> check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order,
> copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, multi_output,
> ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, y_numeric, estimator)
> 825     else:
> 826         y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
> --> 827         _assert_all_finite(y)
> 828     if y_numeric and y.dtype.kind == 'O':
> 829         y = y.astype(np.float64)
>
> D:\Software\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in
> _assert_all_finite(X, allow_nan, msg_dtype)
> 101                 not allow_nan and not np.isfinite(X).all()):
> 102             type_err = 'infinity' if allow_nan else 'NaN, infinity'
> --> 103             raise ValueError(
> 104                     msg_err.format
> 105                     (type_err,
>
> ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for
> dtype('float64').

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error is related to the training of the model, which we need to prevent from overfitting

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).